# Generate an alert in Outlook if I don't receive an email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Everyday I have to receive an email xyz.

Is there any plugin for Outlook (or whatever) to get an alert if I don't receive the email?

Comment: This is an old question but unless someone posts something soon I plan on developing this plugin at some point this year. I will try to post it here when done.

Comment: @Jeff did you manage to develop that script?  If so, could you share it with the community?

Comment: Sadly it got back burnered for a bit. I was going to work on it again but stuff broke

Answer (score 3):

If you set a filter to alert you when you receive a message, and possibly even move it to a special folder then you can also set a reminder to ask you, if you have received the email you need today. And you would have a visual indicator, if there is not an unread message.

OR depending on your outlook version, write a simple vba script to check that special folder for an unread message as a scheduled event. If there isn't one alert you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get *any* new message on a regular basis, you could use rules to check that a "got mail from xyz" has been set in the past 24 hours.  Otherwise, the only alternative I see is a custom Outlook add-in (or some VBA macros) that set a timer which goes off every 5 (or whatever) minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should answer the question - I was looking for something similar, as I receive a lot of emails in my work from processes that run at specific times, and was looking for a way to keep track of anything that did not come to my inbox when supposed to.

[Receive a Reminder When a Message Doesn't Arrive? (writen by Diane Poremsky)](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-watch-updates/)

Basically, it details on how to set a *"run a script"* rule that triggers a reminder when you don't get an email within a specified schedule.

The VB code to achieve this is the following:

```
Sub RemindNewMessages(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim objVariant As Variant

Set objInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

' Set the flag/reminder on newly arrived message
 With Item
    .MarkAsTask olMarkThisWeek
    .TaskDueDate = Now + 1
    .ReminderSet = True
    ' Reminder in one hour
    .ReminderTime = Now + 0.041
    .Categories = "Remind in 1 Hour"
    .Save
End With

Item.Save

' look for existing messages and remove the flag and reminder 
For intCount = objInbox.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
 Set objVariant = objInbox.Items.Item(intCount)

 If objVariant.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
    If LCase(objVariant.Subject) = LCase(Item.Subject) And objVariant.SentOn < Item.SentOn Then
' clear flag and category
With objVariant
    .ClearTaskFlag
    .Categories = ""
    .Save
End With

'or just delete the older messages
   '  objVariant.Delete
     Else
    End If
 End If
Next

Set objInbox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about plugins that do what you ask.

You could start with creating a rule.  Hopefully the required email has something you can use to reliably identify it.  For example:  it always comes from a certain sender or it always has certain text in the subject line.  The rule could move the email to a specific folder that you can watch for a new, unread message.  There are other options for what to do that can be combined with moving the email.

Comment: Ok, that changes the question in: "is there any plugin for Outlook (or whatever) to get an alert if some folder does not get a new message every day?"... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, there're filters to run when there's a new message. I wanna a filter (or something) to run if there's no new message.